# Unpacking byte values in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I am attempting to unpack the below data but cannot seem to figure it out.
This is byte data being returned from a digital sound mixer reading meter values from the device.

The documentation suggests the returned blob will be formatted as:

- int1 – length of blob in bytes, 32 bit integer big-endian
- int2 – number of ‘nativefloats’, 32 bit integer little-endian
- ‘nativefloat’ – meter value, 32 bits float little-endian
- ‘nativefloat’
- … (should be a total of 70 ‘nativefloat’ values in this specific message)

performing a print(data) displays the following blob from live data from the device:

```
['F\x00\x00\x00\xd4\xc6\x9a7\xce-\xee8G\xa6=6\x88\x80X7\x83\x99#7\xd1\xd3A7\x88\x80X7\x8cM\x9d7\x9b\xeeK7\xeb,\x847\xd4\xc6\x9a7*q\x8a7dlN7=\xfcU7\xd1\xde\x9f7\xdc\xa4\x817q=\x937b\x9cg7\x1d\xba77\x9b\xeeK7x\xb8q7\x1d^\x807\xe1P?7\x90H\xba7\x1d^\x807o\x86]7\xf8\xf1P7\x88\x80X7\xc5\xa8\xa87:\xdcF7\xdc\x1fe7TaI7\x01\t\xb87.\xebW7\xca\xf3a7\xd6\xef[7=\xfbQ7\xe8\xfa\x957n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54\x9d\xa2\x867n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54\x1e\x93\x867n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54n\xbb\xd54']
```

I have tried several variations of `struct.unpack` but receive "bad char in struct format" and no examples in documentation talk about a layout that resembles this at all.  I have also tried pulling out bytes and converting them using online converters but cannot get anything that resembles an expected value.  I'm sure there is something simple that I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Can you please share what you tried and errors you have received?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I indented your output sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly – please see the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int1` is missing from your example above. It starts with 70 in little-endian, and then proceeds with 70 floats. So you can unpack it with:

```py
int2 = int(*unpack('<i', data[:4]))
floats = unpack('<' + int2*'f', data[4:])
```

If there were an `int1` at the beginning (as described in the provided specification), then you could use

```py
int1 = int(*unpack('>i', data[:4]))
int2 = int(*unpack('<i', data[4:8]))
floats = unpack('<' + int2*'f', data[8:])
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! I am curious as to how you read this to determine that int1 was missing?

Comment: There were two hints that suggested it: the length of data (`len(data) / 4` = 71, not 72) and that decoding the first 4 bytes in big-endian yields 1174405120, which is clearly not the length of the byte stream, while decoding it in little-endian yields 70, which makes sense as `int2`.

Comment: I see! I was trying to use an online converter and it will not show me anything close to those numbers.  Doing it directly in python I can reproduce exactly what you are showing. Thank you!